# Leer un archivo .txt e igualarlo a una string

Tags: c++, archivo

Lo que hacia en linux de cargar el programa a la consola, sólo con un comando en la terminal:

```
./s < EjemplosSudoku.txt
```

en windows no es posible, y asumo que toca cargarlo desde el mismo código, llamando al archivo .txt.

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo? Y una vez cargado, ¿cómo tomar esos caracteres y ponerlos en una string?

> Nota:
>   Es un código de 200 lineas, de resolver sudokus, pero es sólo por así
>   decirlo el solucionador, no pide datos ni nada por el estilo. Estos
>   los recibe de un .txt mientras esté en el formato que debe ser.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar esto: _Lo que hacia en linux de cargar el programa a la consola solo con un comando en windows no es posible_? ¿Qué hacías en Linux? ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código?

Comment: Es un codigo de 200 lineas, de resolver sudokus, pero es solo por asi decirlo el solucionador, no pide datos ni nada por el estilo, Estos los recibe de un .txt mientras este en el formato que debe ser, En linux solamente escribia en la terminal `./s < EjemplosSudoku.txt` y directamente cargaba el archivo al solucionador pero en windows no tengo idea de como cargarle el .txt al solucionador

Comment: Shiro, edita tu pregunta agregando las precisiones que haces en los comentarios. Usa este enlace: [edit].

Answer (score 4):

La consola clásica de Windows no posee redirecciones de entrada, por lo que

```
./s < EjemplosSudoku.txt
```

No te va a servir. Podrías probar leyendo la ruta y el archivo desde el programa:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    char data[100];
    ifstream archivo; 
    archivo.open(argv[1]); // Abris la ruta del archivo pasada por parametro

    cout << "Leyendo archivo" << endl; 
    archivo >> data; 

    archivo.close();
}
```

Y lo ejecutás de la siguiente manera:

```
./s EjemplosSudoku.txt
```

Esto es válido tanto para Linux como para Windows. Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Saludos!